# The proportion of time Y that an industrial robot is in operation during a 40-hour week is a random variable with probability density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The proportion of time Y that an industrial robot is in operation during a 40-hour week is a random variable with probability density function.
$$f(y) = \begin{cases} 2y & 0 \leq y \leq 1  \\ 0 & elsewhere \end{cases}$$

For the robot under study, the profit X for a week is given by
$$X = 200Y - 60$$

Find an interval in which the profit should lie for at least 75% of the weeks that the robot is in use.

I found a solution on [Slader](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/the-proportion-of-time-y-that-an-industrial-robot-is-in-operation-during-a-40-hour-week-is-a-random/). The solution is solving the equation $P(\mu - y \leq Y \leq \mu + y) = 0.75$.

I do not understand why he split 2 side equally like that. And I want to ask is there any other solution?

Comment: how is profit related to the proportion that the robot is in use?

Comment: I forgot the X. I’ve just added to the post.